# On Mac OS X, Firefox displays my website all messed up

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox

If you goto blgz.co on firefox on a mac, the right side bar is sitting on top of the main content. It works on firefox on windows, just the mac version. I can't pinpoint what the problem is. =( Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reformat the div hierarchy like this:

```
<div id="content">
 <div id="content-inner"></div>
 <div id="sidebar-first"></div>
 <div id="sidebar-second"></div>
</div>
```

and float them all left.
the issue is that the #content-inner is now inside #content and as I understood, the sidebar-second should float to the #content-inner.
however, the structure of divs seems to me too much complicated for such a simple layout..

Comment: That wouldn't work because some parts of the website dont use the sidebars and the main content would have to resize itself to fit.